# determine efficiently which rectangle a point is in 2d space

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, html5-canvas, kdtree

I have a large set of rectangles that are drawn on html5 canvas.

[image]

I would like to be able to interact with this image using mouse tracking (I cannot use SVG because it does not scale to 10-100k rectangles). Is there any data structure/algo that, given the mouse x,y coordinates would be able to tell you which box the mouse was over (using the computed locations of the rectangles)? I was thinking something like a k-d tree but was not sure.

Answer (score 6):

If your data is always of the form shown I think you should be able to do better than a spatial tree data structure.

Since the data is structured in `y` you should be able to calculate which 'strip' of rectangles the points is in based on offsets in `O(1)` time.

If you store the individual rectangles within each 'strip' in sorted order (using `xmax` say) you should then be able to locate the specific rectangle within the strip using a binary search (in `O(log(n))`).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution would be to iterate over all rectangles and check if you are in it. Checking for a single rectangle is easy (if you want I will write it down explicitly).

If you have many rectangles and care about performance, you can easily speed things up by putting the rectangles in a data structure which is faster to look in. Looking at the image you sent, one obvious property of your data is that there is a limited amount of vertical positions ("rows"). This means that if you check which row you are on, you then only need to check rectangles within that row. Finally, to select which row you are on or within a row select which rectangle, keep a sorted data structure (e.g. some search tree).

So your data structure could be something like a search tree for row, where each node holds a search tree of rectangles along the row.

Answer (score 0):

[R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is suitable for providing spatial access of this kind

But some questions:

Is your rectangle set static or dynamic?

How many point queries do you expect for rectangle set?

**Edit:**

Because rectangle set is static:
There is method, used in traditional graphics with bitmaps (don't know is it applicable to html5 canvas or not):

Make additional bitmap with the same size as main picture. Draw every rectangle with the same coordinates, but fill it with unique color (for example, color = rectangle index). Then check color under mouse point => get rectangle index in O(1)

Comment: the rectangles will be static in that new rectangles will not be added. Potentially many queries

Comment: thats really clever. ill take a look. would the 'encoded' image be transparent or would it need to be visible?

Comment: It would be invisible, some kind of back buffer. Just use mouse coordinate at main window with this invisible picture.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to get the color? What command would you use?

Comment: You can get the color of a pixel in a canvas image with [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas). Then you assemble the color into a hex-string, which you can use to look up the corresponding object.